# Process.Equals() doesn't work

Tags: c#

```
if (Process.Equals(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), Process.GetCurrentProcess()))
            Console.WriteLine("i am the same as my self");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("i am not the same as my self");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

it prints "i am not the same as my self"

what is the problem ?

and how i can use the `Equals(Object a, Object b)` Function ?, any examples please ?

Comment: Because each `GetCurrentProcess()` returns a new instance, [as documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: The Process class does not override Equals(), it is pretty ambiguous whether it ought to check for exact object identity, exact OS object identity or check if two distinct OS objects represent different instances of the same executable.  Process.GetCurrentProcess() is a static method, it creates a new Process object every time you call it.  Since Object.Equals is being used, you'll get false since they are different objects.  Consider comparing the Id properties, probably what you meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't override the `Equals` method, so the one from it's base class [`System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) is used which just compares references. It seems [`Process.GetCurrentProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess(v=vs.110).aspx) returns always new instances which means they are not the same reference.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) mentions it already:

> Gets a **new** Process component and associates it with the currently
>   active process.....
>   Use this method to create a **new Process** instance and associate it with the process resource on the local computer.

if you look at it's [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,a106ad886675f6a5,references) you see `new Process(...)`(read [`new`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator)):

```
public static Process GetCurrentProcess() {
    return new Process(".", false, NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcessId(), null);
}
```

If you want to check if two process instances are equal, you could write a custom comparer:

```
public class ProcessIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<System.Diagnostics.Process>
{
    public bool Equals(Process x, Process y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Process obj)
    {
        return obj?.Id.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can check if both have the same ID:

```
Process p1 = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Process p2 = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

bool equalProcesses = new ProcessIdComparer().Equals(p1, p2); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

Classes are not *required* to provide an equality definition. The `Equals` you're looking at here is `object.Equals(object,object)`, and it so happens that `Process` does not override this. So what you are testing is *reference equality*.

You have *two different object instances* - that *represent* the same OS process. To see if they represent the same OS process: compare the process id (the `Id` property of the `Process` instance).

Comment: _"compare the process id"_ - and perhaps the StartTime and machinename, because PIDs can be reused and Process instances aren't bound to one machine.